# Sum up data by month in Pandas ( Not Year-Month)

Tags: python, pandas

I hope to sum up data by month ONLY. i.e.

```
01/07/2010   10
02/16/2011   12
01/16/2012   11
```

This is what I want:

```
Jan : 21
Feb : 12
```

This is not like

```
df.resample('MS')
```

because row 1 and 3 are from different years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming your index is `datetimeindex`

then its just a matter of

`df.groupby(df.index.month).sum()`

otherwise its still simple

`df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.month).sum()`

Comment: I like the noo name... Avatar still needs some work (-;

Comment: @piRSquared this is the best manga ever buddy: Jojo's bizarre adventures

Comment: I'll have to look it up I guess, before I start slingin' trash talk

Comment: ( @Arthur if that works for the answer, you can mark it as such by clicking the check mark left of the post, below the up/down arrows)

Comment: @BruceWayne "You can't accept an answer in 9 mins." LOL

Comment: @ℕℴℴḆḽḘ I got an interesting result when using apply() function. If you use df.groupby(df.index.month).apply(lambda x:x.ewm(com=2).mean()) you get the wrong answer. However if you use df.groupby(df.index.month).apply(lambda x:pd.ewma(com=2).mean()) then you get the correct answer. (This will calculate the ewma within the group).

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this ?

df.groupby(df.Date.astype(str).str[:2]).sum()
     sum
01   21
02   12
```

Comment: Ty for your solution XD

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.Timestamp('2010-01-07'), pd.Timestamp('2011-02-16'), pd.Timestamp('2012-01-16')], 'val': [10, 12, 11]})
>>> df.groupby(df['date'].dt.strftime("%b")).sum()
     val
date     
Feb    12
Jan    21
```

Comment: Ty for your solution!